# Stuck in Workflow

Tags: workflow

My work flow formula is :

```
OR( ISCHANGED( Info_Kit_Request_Date__c ) ,ISCHANGED( Info_Kit_Type__c ), AND( ISPICKVAL( Info_Kit_Type__c ,Nut Rake) ) )
```

Its giving me an error "Syntex error :found Nut"

I want to use below statements in workflow.

1. `OR( ISCHANGED( Info_Kit_Request_Date__c ) ,ISCHANGED( Info_Kit_Type__c )`
2. `AND( ISPICKVAL( Info_Kit_Type__c ,Nut Rake) )`

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing Nut Rake within Double quotes like below.

> AND( ISPICKVAL( Info_Kit_Type__c ,"Nut Rake") )

As you have not put Nut Rake within Double quotes so it is showing u a syntax error.

You can refer [this link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/picklist_formulas) to use Picklist Values in the formula.